# Tab bar doesn't show up iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Added Tab bar view controller to my project and it doesn't show up in the app, it shows up in interface builder, but not in the app. And when I go to the Cards view controller it shows a black line above toolbar (second pic). What could be the problem here?

[image]
[image]

```
    class CardsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
        
        var cards: Results<Card>?
        let realm = try! Realm()
        var cardFromResult: Card?
        var alreadyHighLighted: Bool = false
        var cellIndexPath: IndexPath? {
            didSet {
                if !alreadyHighLighted {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: self.cellIndexPath!, at: .middle, animated: true)
                        self.tableView.selectRow(at: self.cellIndexPath!, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.7) {
                        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: self.cellIndexPath!, animated: true)
                        self.alreadyHighLighted = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var selectedDeck: Deck? {
            didSet {
                loadCards()
            }
        }
        
        @IBOutlet var reviewButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            navigationItem.title = selectedDeck?.name
            tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        }
        
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            tableView.reloadData()
            if cards?.count == 0 {
                navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
            } else {
                navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
            }
        }
        
        override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
            navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
        }
}
```

Comment: "when I go to the Cards view controller"  You are the only who knows what that view controller is.

Comment: added code for cards view controller